# Contador no se sigue ejecutando

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola he tratado de hacer un contador con Java , al momento de ejecutar el código el contador no funciona pero ya he tratado de colocar ciclo for , while , pero nada arranca este es mi código, pensaria que el error esta en los métodos que cree para incrementar y decrementar , o tal vez en la clase main a l ahora de obtener el valor del contador

```
package counter;

public class Counter {

    private int counter = 0;
    static int decision;

    public Counter() {

    }
    
    

    public Counter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;

    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void increase() {
        if(counter  >= 0 ) {
         counter++;
           

        }

    }

    public void decrease() {
        if (counter <= 0) {
          counter =  counter--;

        }

    }

}
```

```
package counter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CounterMain extends Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Counter countermain = new Counter();

        System.out.println("give me a number");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        
        countermain.setCounter(number);

        System.out.println(countermain.getCounter());

        countermain.increase();
        System.out.println(countermain.getCounter());

        countermain.decrease();
        System.out.println(countermain.getCounter());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu condicional en el método `decrease()`:

```
public void decrease() {
    if (counter <= 0) {
      counter =  counter--;

    }

}
```

Allí sólamente se modificará el contador si el mismo es menor o igual a cero.

Tienes dos opciones, depende de la necesidad de tu código:

### Opción 1

Hacer decremento sin condiciones, si el código debe producir también valores negativos:

```
public void decrease() {
  counter--;
}
```

### Opción 2

Verificar solamente si el valor es mayor a cero, si el código no debe producir valores negativos:

```
public void decrease() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      counter--;
    }
}
```

### Demos

Aquí te dejo dos demostraciones, una con cada opción.

- <kbd>[Demo Opción 1](https://rextester.com/TFI65076)</kbd>
- <kbd>[Demo Opción 2](https://rextester.com/CEMVW83628)</kbd>

Comment: Hola ya intente hacerlo de las dos formas ... pero al momento que corro el incrementar no pasa nada, solo me imprime 4 veces el mismo numero de counter y hasta alli llega el codigo.

Comment: @newezzio al final de la respuesta te he puesto dos demos con cada opción. El código funciona, si en tu caso no lo hace, debe ser por otro motivo.

Comment: En dado caso ambos métodos estarían mal, pues si al decrementar el contador llega a números negativos, entonces ya no puede incrementar

Comment: @EduardoJiménez no, no están mal ambos métodos. En el caso que expones, la **Opción 2** sería la adecuada, se controlaría hasta `0` y en caso de ser `0`: deja de decrementar, mientras que el incremento funciona normalmente.